# Conditional Formatting of a column based on values of another column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two columns in a spreadsheet both with text values and over 30,000 rows. I need to highlight the cells in column B if the text from column A exists in column B. So, if the text in A23 is found in B23, highlight B23. I need this done to all the rows in a single formula.

Answer (score 2):

You use words like "is found" and "exists", so I assume the two cells will not be a perfect match, but text from column A is part of the text in column B.

In this case, select the values in column B, starting with B1. Then add a new conditional format with a rule and this formula:

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A1,B1))
```

Note that there are no $ signs in the cell references!!

[image]

Comment: Note that there are no $ signs in the cell references!!! -- THANKS!